# Custom sort methods are not being called in lazy loading Primefaces datatable

Tags: sorting, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have method calls included for custom sorting of Strings and numeric types in my Primefaces datatable component. The non-lazy datatables' sortings are working perfectly well in the current situation. But when I switch to lazy-loading, the custom sorting methods aren't called (debugged correctly) although I have the needed load implementation and I can lazy load my data with no flaws. Since my own methods are not being called, sorting errors do occur with PF's own sorting mechanisms. It sorts the data but having troubles with foreign characters of our alphabet, also the numerics are treated like Strings etc.

The question is: How can I make my own sort functions called properly with lazy-loading?

I'm using Primefaces 5.0, JSF 2.2 Mojarra, JDK 1.7, WebLogic server

p.s: off-topic attributes (filters etc.) are omitted.

```xhtml
<p:dataTable id="resourceDataTable" var="result" widgetVar="someWidgetVar"
         value="#{someBean.someDataModel.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rowKey="#{result.id}"
         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rows="5" styleClass="incidentDatatableClass"
         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
         currentPageReportTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
         lazy="true" rowSelectMode="checkbox">

        <p:column width="7">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="resourceCheckbox" value="#{result.selected}" style="margin-top: 4px;">
                <p:ajax listener="#{copResourceBean.resourceDataModel.selectionChanged(result)}" update=":resourceForm:selectedResourcePanel"/>
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="resourceName" headerText="#{language['someHeader']}" sortBy="#{result.name}" 
                  sortFunction="#{helper.sortString}">
            <h:outputText value="#{result.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="facilityName"  sortBy="#{result.facilityName}" sortFunction="#{helper.sortString}" headerText="#{language['someHeader']}" >
            <h:outputText value="#{result.facilityName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="availableQuantity" headerText="#{language['someHeader']}" width="80" sortBy="#{result.availableQuantity}" 
                  sortFunction="#{helper.sortNumeric}" >
            <h:outputText value="#{result.availableQuantity}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: That is as expected. With lazy loading you need to do the sorting IN the load method of your LazyDataModel

Comment: yes. as it was clearly stated in pg. 161 :) I missed the solution by 8 minutes because I was lazy-loading the needed data! (ew. ok, that was bad) can you post it as a response so that we can tell the world the problem is solved?http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The custom sort (or filter functions/methods) do not work when using lazy loading, nor are they intended to. In the case of lazy loading, you should implement the sorting/filtering in the load method of the LazyDatamodel implementation.

Comment: IMHO this should be documented. One of the `load()` methods of `LazyDataModel` receives `SortMeta`s, which may carry sort functions, so in theory a `LazyDataModel` implementation **could** apply custom sort functions. Depending on scenario, this of course may require to apply proper strategies for efficient pagination, but why not supporting it at all?

Comment: 2 reasons. 1: Has never been requested (or a problem) 2: complexity of the implementation in relation to the (rarely) requested functionality. And it has never been a problem that this was never documented

Comment: No problem is a problem until someone says it's a problem... The LazyDataModel API, which has a lot of flaws anyway, is inconsistent with regards to this aspect and this inconsistency is not even documented as the desired behaviour. This is a fact. If you're saying that it's "good enough" for most people and you're happy with it, that's fine. I don't think this is the right approach towards improvement, though. After all, you never had one, from JBoss times to PrimeFaces now...

Comment: I'm not saying things cannot be improved, there might very well be (is?) room for improvement, and I'm not saying a small remark cannot be added about the 'use a lazy datamodel OR custom sort (or filtering for that matter). But stating it **should** be documented is IMHO to bald (even it if you added IMHO ;-). And baldly stating _has a lot of flaws anyway_ without stating which ones (or better, create issues in the issus list) is even less forward to improving. I'm  open for a lot of things, including improvement